# Java Puzzle on Garbage Collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection

We have 2 objects `A` and `B` in Java; `A` creates `B`.

Now we make `A` to get garbage collected by making `A = null` or by other means. Challenge here is that `B` should get garbage collected.

We just have 2 objects and one creates other. The newly Created object should not get garbage collected while the earlier object is garbage collected. Just wanted to know is that possible in Java? Let me know for more info.

Thanks!

Comment: I think B will get collected when it goes out of scope / is no longer used.

Comment: If you don't want `B` to be garbage collected you need to keep its reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter who created B. As long as B is being referred somewhere it will not be garbage collected.

So, lets say,

```
private static B getB(){
   A a = new A();
   B b = a.getB();
   a = null; // not really required it will be gone as soon as I get out of this method.
   return b;
}


public void addToALookupMap(){
    B b = getB();
    aStaticFinalLookupMap.put(b.getId(), b); //b is not garbage collected until the map get, at least
}
```